# Can I connect a resistive touch panel to the iPad?

Tags: ipad, accessories, lightning

I am wondering if it would be possible to connect a resistive touch panel (manufactured with a 30-pin connector) to the iPad through the 30-pin connection and use that for input?

Comment: For what program? If this is a developer question, it's off-topic here. If this is about existing programs, I don't know of any that support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No chance I'm afraid, the limiting factor is software more than anything though, it's possible that an App could be written to talk to said accessory, but using it outside of that App would not be possible unless you are talking about a highly modified jailbroken solution.

Unless you already have a device in mind that exists which you actually want to use, I can't imagine anyone creating one, and if they did not by the dock connector, but more likely over a custom Bluetooth protocol which is allowed (see the i-Cade games cabinet for example of a custom controller using Bluetooth that only works with supported apps).

You may be better mentioning what you wish to achieve to allow alternate answers, as I am almost positive that this method will never fly.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the input. I would only want it to work in a specific app so I think it would be great. I thought it was possible because of the arcade docks that are out there (which you mentioned). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to connect an external touchscreen capable of sending input to iphone:
http://www.macstories.net/iphone/the-external-touchscreen-that-can-control-an-iphone/